# Understanding the syntax for Column vs Row indexing in R

Tags: r, indexing, row, multiple-columns

I'm a bit confused on the filtering scheme on an R data frame.

For example, let's say we have the following data frame titled `dframe`:

```
> str(dframe)
'data.frame':   143 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Year     : int  1999 2005 2007 2008 2009 2010 2005 2006 2007 2008 ...
 $ Name     : Factor w/ 18 levels "AADAM","AADEN",..: 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Frequency: int  5 6 10 34 38 12 10 6 10 5 ...
```

Now if I want to filter `dframe` where the values of Name is of "AADAM", the proper filter is:
`dframe[dframe$Name=="AADAM",]`

The part where I'm confused is why the comma doesn't come first. Why isn't it this: `dframe[,dframe$Name=="AARUSH"]`

Comment: You need to look at the result of `dframe$Name == "AADAM"` to start to understand this. It will return a logical vector that will tell you the rows where `"AADAM"` was found.

Comment: Why do you think the comma should come first? The indexing does [(rows you want), (cols you want)] and leaving one blank returns them all.

Comment: `dframe[dframe$Name=="AADAM",]` is basically like saying "Give me all the rows of `dframe` such that the `Name` column is always `AADAM`"

Comment: ^ ... which is a meaningless expression within a column. Meaningful for rows only.

Comment: @smci that's how it's being used. It's subsetting on the rows.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: You clarified your question is really *"Please give examples of what sort of logical expressions are valid for filtering columns?"*

I agree with you the syntax appears weird initially, but it has the following logic.

The bottom line is that column-filter expressions are typically less rich and expressive than row-filtering expressions, and in particular you can't chain logical indexing the way you do with rows.

Best way is to think of indexing expressions as the general form:

```
dframe[<row-index-expression>,<col-index-expression>]
```

where **either index-expression is optional**, so you can just do one and we (crucially!) need the comma to disambiguate whether it's row- or column-indexing:

```
dframe[<row-index-expression>,] # such as dframe[dframe$Name=="ADAM",]

dframe[,<col-index-expression>]
```

Before we look at examples of `col-index-expression` and what's valid (and invalid) to include in one, let's review and discuss how R does indexing - I had the same confusion when I started with it.

In this example, you have three columns. You can refer to them by their string names ***'Year','Name','Frequency'***. You can also refer to them by column indices ***1,2,3*** where the numbers 1,2,3 correspond to the entries `colnames(dframe)`. R does indexing using the '[' operator, also the '[[' operator. Here are some valid examples of ways to index column-indexing:

```
dframe[,2]       # column 2 / Name
dframe[,'Name']  # column 2 / Name
dframe[,c('Name','Frequency')]  # string vector - very common
dframe[,c(2,3)]                 # integer vector - also very common
dframe[,c(F,T,T)]               # logical vector - very rarely seen, and a pain in the butt to compute
```

Now, if you choose to use a logical expression for the column-index, it must be a valid expression without using column names - inside a column it doesn't know their own names.
Suppose you wanted to dynamically filter "give me only the factor columns from dframe".
Something like:

```
unlist(apply(dframe[1,1:3], 2, is.factor), use.names=F) # except I can't seem to remove the colnames
```

For more help and examples on indexing look at the `'['` operator help-page:
Type `?'['`

`dframe[,dframe$Name=="ADAM"]` is invalid attempt at column-indexing because the columns know nothing about Name=="ADAM"

Addendum: code to generate example dataframe (because you didn't dump us a `dput` output)

```
set.seed(123)
N = 10
randomName <- function() { cat(sample(letters, size=runif(1)*6+2, replace=T), sep='') }    
dframe = data.frame(Year=round(runif(N,1980,2014)),
                    Name = as.factor(replicate(N, randomName())),
                    Frequency=round(runif(N, 2,40)))
```

Comment: I understand that the row-indexing expression comes first, but what would be an example of a column-indexing expression? Would this be a valid one (I can't test this at this moment): `dframe[,dframe$Name]`? Or how would I grab two of the 3 columns?

Comment: Ah ok. Your question is really *'Please give examples of what sort of logical expressions are valid for filtering columns?'*

Comment: I guess that's one of the questions I'm asking. I can't find any good examples of filtering columns with logical expressions

Comment: Filtering ***columns*** with ***logical*** expressions (computed from the columns themselves, not just logical constants, or vectors of integers, which are both easy) is a giant pain in the butt. It's rarely done and it's a syntactical nightmare. The language needn't have been designed to be so, but it was, so that's how it is. I've been trying to cook you up elegant examples of that, but they all suck.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember that when you're sub-setting, the part before the comma is specifying which rows you want, and the part after the comma is specifying which columns you want. ie:

```
dframe[rowsyouwant, columnsyouwant]
```

You're filtering based on columns, but you want all of the columns in your result, so the space after the comma is blank. You want some sub-set of rows, so your filtering specification goes before the comma, where the rows you want are specified.

Answer (score 2):

As others have indicated, requesting a certain subset of a data frame requires the syntax `[rows, columns]`. Since `dframe[has 143 rows, has 3 columns]`, any request for some part of `dframe` should be of the form

```
dframe[which of the 143 rows do I want?, which of the 3 columns do I want?].
```

Because `dframe$Name` is a vector of length 143, the comparison `dframe$Name=='AADAM'` is a vector of T/F values that also has length 143. So,

```
dframe[dframe$Name=='AADAM',]
```

is like saying

```
dframe[of the 143 rows I want these ones, I want all columns]
```

whereas

```
dframe[,dframe$Name=='AADAM']
```

generates an error because it's like saying

```
dframe[I want all rows, of the 143 columns I want these ones]
```

On a side note, you may want to look into the `subset()` function if you're not already familiar with it. You could get the same result by writing `subset(dframe, Name=='AADAM')`

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the structure within brackets is `row`, then `column`.

One way I think of the syntax of selecting data from a `data.frame` using:

```
dframe[dframe$Name=="AADAM",]
```

is to think of a noun, then a verb where:

`dframe[]` is the noun.  It is the object on which you want to perform an action

and

`[dframe$Name=="AADAM",]` is the verb.  It is the action you want to perform.

I have a silly way of expressing this to myself, but it keeps things straight in my mind:

Hey, you!  `dframe`!  I am going to...  ...in this case, select all of your `rows` in which `Name` is equal to `AADAM`!

By keeping the column portion of `[dframe$Name=="AADAM",]` blank you are saying you want to keep all columns.

Sometimes it can be a little difficult to remember that you have to write `dframe` both inside and outside the brackets.

As for exactly why `row` comes first and `column` comes second, I do not know, but `row` had to be either first or second.

```
dframe <- read.table(text = '
     Year Name Frequency
       1  ADAM     4
       3  BOB     10
       7  SALLY    5
       2  ADAM    12
       4  JIM      3
      12  ADAM     7
', header = TRUE)

dframe[,dframe$Name=="ADAM"]

# Error in `[.data.frame`(dframe, , dframe$Name == "ADAM") : 
#   undefined columns selected

dframe[dframe$Name=="ADAM",]

#   Year Name Frequency
# 1    1 ADAM         4
# 4    2 ADAM        12
# 6   12 ADAM         7

dframe[,'Name']

# [1] ADAM  BOB   SALLY ADAM  JIM   ADAM 
# Levels: ADAM BOB JIM SALLY


dframe[dframe$Name=="ADAM",'Name']

# [1] ADAM ADAM ADAM
# Levels: ADAM BOB JIM SALLY
```

Comment: Row-major indexing is standard in mathematics.  Also, usually one row of a database table refers to one entity, and the different columns are the different values associated with that entity. So table[row,] has a definite referent, while table[,column] is a collection of disjoint values.